# How to modify Scrollview height dynamically in react native

Tags: react-native, scrollview

I have a scroll view with a full-length screen. With one flag I need to show button at the bottom. 
Am using **Animated.View** for showing button at Bottom.
When button visible am unable to change scroll view height.
If I try to manage with **marginBottom** it is showing unwanted white before getting a button with animation.

Here I need to do either change scroll view height dynamically or transparent unwanted white background.

Below is code snippet:

```
    const modalY = new Animated.Value(Dimensions.get('window').height);

openModal = () => {
    Animated.timing(modalY, {
        duration: 500,
        toValue: Dimensions.get('window').height - 60
     }).start();
  }

  closeModal = () => {
    Animated.timing(modalY, {
        duration: 300,
        toValue: Dimensions.get('window').height
     }).start();
  }

showButton = () => {
    const animationView = <Animated.View style={[ {width: Dimensions.get('window').width,position: 'absolute'}, { transform:                        [{translateY: modalY}] }]}>
                          <TouchableHighlight    with title height 60/>
                      </Animated.View>;

    return (
      animationView
    );
  };


const marBottom = buttonTitle ? 60 : 0;
```

here buttonTitle is flag

```
<View>
        <ScrollView contentContainerStyle={{ paddingTop: top }} style={{marginBottom:marBottom}}>
            <View style={ [styles.itemscontainer]}>
              { this.myItems()}
            </View>
        </ScrollView>
        { this.showButton() }
        {(buttonTitle) ? this.openModal() : this.closeModal()}
      </View>
```

[image: Unwanted white space before button visible with animation]

Comment: Have you tried `flexGrow` and `flexShrink`?

Comment: @ThomasKekeisen Yes, no change